# Unable to consume messages from an embedded remote broker in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, remote-access, messagebroker

I am an ActiveMQ begginer. My main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

        if(isProducer(args)){
            broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:8001");

            broker.start();
            // start producer...
        }
        else{
            broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:9000"); 
            broker.addNetworkConnector("static:(tcp://localhost:8001)");

            broker.start(); // Getting stuck here!!!
            // start consumer
        }

        waitForever();
```

}

I start this application twice, once a a producer and once as a consumer.
When I start the consumer, it gets stuck on the broker.start() line.

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicly you start the broker once (embedding it into a jvm).

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.setUseJmx(true);
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start();
```

Then you connect to the broker (this code is needed in both consumer and producer application):

```
url = "vm://localhost:61616"    //if you are in same jvm
url2 = "tcp://localhost:61616"   //if you are in diff jvm or other host
connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username,password,url);
connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(transacted, ackMode);
```

Then setup a consumer

```
Destination queue = session.createQueue("queuename");
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageConsumer());
```

Setup a producer and send a message

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
objectMessage.setObject(object);
producer.send(objectMessage);
```

look at for example: http://jmsexample.zcage.com/index2.html

or http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/branches/activemq-5.6/assembly/src/release/example/src/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. The broker is listening on TCP transport. How come I can specify vm://?

Comment: Im on thin ice here, but i think the connectors you add are the ones needed for transport. Using vm:// you will invoke methods directly in the same vm, so no transport connector needed